# Product Output by SKU

Tags: template, products, widget

I want to load a set of products, given as an array:

```
<?php
$productSkus = array('sku-1','sku-2');

foreach($productSkus as $productSku) :
    $productId = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getIdBySku($productSku);
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $productName = $_product->getName();
    echo $productName;
endforeach;
?>
```

As I am a rookie I'm wondering if this set is not a lot of database requests. Is there a way to do the loading before the loop at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `addAttributeToFilter`

```
$productSkus = array('sku-1','sku-2');
$productCollection=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
       ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('in' => $productSkus))
       ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach($productCollection as $_product)
{
     echo $_product->getName();
}
```

Comment: I get a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '*' in`

Comment: that was a type-error. i missed the single quotes. check the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use product collection and filter them by sku using in clause.

```
    $Collection=Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
      -->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array(
        'in' => $productSkus,
        ))
     ->addAttributeToSelect('name') // for get Name;
;



foreach($Collection as $eachproduct) :
echo $eachproduct>getName();
endforeach;
```

For getting more details on filter see [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento)